# AppEngine: restore original builtin open/file function

Tags: python, google-app-engine, assets

What is the easiest way to restore original builtin open/file function in AppEngine dev_appserver? I need this to get working assets manager in development environment (compiling multiple JS/CSS files).

Comment: Why do you need to do this? The dev_appserver is explcitly designed to emulate the production environment; if you need to do something you couldn't do in production, you shouldn't be doing it inside your App Engine app.

Comment: @Nick Johnson, I need it to generate my assets (merge/compress JS/CSS files). This will be done only in development env (i.e. precompilation). django-mediagenerator is good example of such assets manager, but I need one for Flask.

Comment: You should do it outside the dev_appserver, using a build script.

Comment: Probably, but is is a lot easier to disable HardenedModuleHook to get working flask-webassets on both production/development then writing my own build script.

Comment: Why is writing your own build script so hard? It's the same thing, only you don't have to monkey around with the SDK internals, and it won't break at random when we change the undocumented stuff you're relying on.

Comment: Main point - I have to invoke it whenever I change css/js file. Otherwise it should monitor changed files, merge them, compile (in case of coffee/scss), maintain modification timestamp (gen.css?11111). It is not hard, but it requires some work.

Comment: make and other build systems do almost all of that for you; or you can just run the build script on every deploy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write to file system changing the `FakeFile.ALLOWED_MODES` flags.

```
from google.appengine.tools import dev_appserver
allowed_modes = dev_appserver.FakeFile.ALLOWED_MODES
dev_appserver.FakeFile.ALLOWED_MODES = frozenset(['w'])
f = open('test.txt', 'w')
f.write('this is a test')
f.close()
dev_appserver.FakeFile.ALLOWED_MODES = allowed_modes
```

Answer (score 2):

Same as approved answer. But for latest version compatible fix:

```
if os.environ.get("SERVER_SOFTWARE", "").startswith("Dev"):
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.python import stubs
    stubs.FakeFile.ALLOWED_MODES = frozenset(["a", "r", "w", "rb", "U", "rU"])
```